# How to change Terms text on paypal payment listing page

Tags: paypal

When the "Buy Now" button is clicked and the user is redirected to the Paypal.com order page the "Terms" column text for the order does not read well. It is a bit confusing to some users.

Example as displayed on my Paypal.com order page:

Terms: $25.00 USD for each 24 months

I created a test "Buy Now" button my Paypal account(not through lm_module), with a recurring billing to see how Paypal displays terms.

Example as displayed on my Paypal.com order page:

Terms: $25.00 USD for each month

When comparing both "Terms" I see that the lm_module adds the "Regular billing cycle" number to the "Terms" on the Paypal order page, and also the "Regular billing cycle units."

It looks like the output is implemented like: (Regular rate) for each (Regular billing cycle units) (Regular billing cycle)

Does anyone know how this can be edited to a more reader friendly terms?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Do you got any working solution? Because I have a same issue. Please,share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your form with the "a3"(amount), "p3" (interval count), "t3" (interval), and "scr" (is recurring) hidden fields:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribe_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3" value="5.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

NOTE: This does not work with the "hosted button".

Source: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_subscr_techview_outside